# Toggle menu on click of two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var main = function() {
    $('#menu-open').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({ left: '0px' }, 200);
        $('body').animate({ left: '285px' }, 200);
    });
    $('#menu-close').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({ left: '-285px' }, 200);
        $('body').animate({ left: '0px' }, 200);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

I want to be able to close the menu with the click of `#menu-close` or `#menu-open` when the menu is open. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have 2 different elements (menu-open and menu-close) to click or there is one element?
If you just want to close/show the menu, you can use toggle() function form jQuery, like this: $('.menu').toggle();
[link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @RicardoPontual they are two seperate elements. I want to be able to click the close or open button once it is opened to close it. I have it working , you just have to hit one button to open it and one to close it. I will see if i can get the toggle function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind single function to both open/close button. Inside the function, check the menu status. Example:

```
$('.menu-open, .menu-close').click(function() {
    var left = $('.menu').offset().left;

    if (left < 0) {
        $('.menu').animate({ left: 0 }, 200);
        $('body').animate({ left: 285 }, 200);
    } else {
        $('.menu').animate({ left: -285 }, 200);
        $('body').animate({ left: 0 }, 200);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

This is updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdaen/jsf0oc99/3/

Comment: I'm not following you. Here is jsfiddle - (https://jsfiddle.net/nxtst/jsf0oc99/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. :(

Comment: I basically plugged it in and it didn't work. Could you give me a bit more context, like where I should put it or if i should plug anything in? Like I said, I'm a noob.